# SSIS Fuzzy Lookup for dates

Tags: sql-server, ssis, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I am trying to match clients using three fields: FirstName, LastName, Gender, and DOB. It's my understanding that SSIS Fuzzy Lookup only applies to strings (never seen this in documentations, just some bloggers said so) so in this scenario, could I somehow use DOB to build "confidence"? How does this tool compare the dates?

Here is a thread on this issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d2e53f8c-abfc-461e-9263-fd46b95247c0/ssis-fuzzy-lookup-and-dates?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms137786.aspx) says that it will do an exact lookup on non-STR columns. Any reasons why you can't convert DOB to a string before doing the fuzzy transform?

Comment: Thank you, I found the excerpt, for some reason I didn't find that in the first read: "Only input columns with the DT_WSTR and DT_STR data types can be used in fuzzy matching. Exact matching can use any DTS data type except DT_TEXT, DT_NTEXT, and DT_IMAGE. "

Comment: @ESG : "why can't I convert DOB", that would defeat the purpose entirely. That was followed by some folks in that thread I cited. The fuzzy matching won't match "one" to "two", rather it may match "two" to "twoo" or "twi". It works based on distance formula and common typos, and typo combinations. Converting digits to strings, simply won't do anything because you'll never make a mistake.

Comment: Understandable. In that case, you might be better off writing your own scripting component to weight the different parameters yourself. For example, for a DOB, I would assume that the month+data value is of stronger relevance than the year. Or, alternatively, the number of days between the DOB column and the provided value is what matters. In either cases, a scripting component is probably what gives you the best flexibility.

Comment: @ESG that's a very good suggestion too (to use weights) - I'll experiment with the scripting. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do a lot of Name/DOB searches and it's really difficult to get right. You can consider sorting using a function similar to the one below. This will basically take two 8-digit dates (YYYYMMDD) and count the number of miss-matched digits.

For example these date pairs have 1 miss-matched digit:

- 1976-10-20 and 1976-01-20 (10 vs 01)
- 1976-10-20 and 1975-10-20 (76 vs 75)

Depending on how much data dealing with, this is good for sorting (aka putting your best match first) but not for filtering (because there is no indexing involved).

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.BirthDateRank ( @DOB1 DATE, @DOB2 DATE )
RETURNS INT
AS
    BEGIN
        -- 10/31/2016 --> 10312016
        DECLARE @xDOB1 VARCHAR(10) = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @DOB1, 101), '/', '');
        DECLARE @xDOB2 VARCHAR(10) = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), @DOB2, 101), '/', '');

        DECLARE @i INT = 0;
        DECLARE @iRet INT = 0;

        WHILE @i <= LEN(@xDOB1)
        BEGIN
            SET @iRet = @iRet + CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@xDOB1, @i, 1) = SUBSTRING(@xDOB2, @i, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END

            SET @i = @i + 1
        END

        RETURN @iRet;

    END;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is such an excellent suggestion. However, I am trying to trace the function to see what it does; so this returns the number of mismatched digits? For instance: 1945-02-23 and 1944-03-23 returns TWO because 45 vs. 44 has ONE mismatch and 02 vs. 03 has another one? Thanks!

Comment: You got it! Just remember this is best for sorting smaller datasets and not millions of rows.

Comment: sorry no idea why i had not chosen the best answer before